# More elegant proof: Sets of sequences with a common prefix form a base for Baire space.

Tags: general-topology

Baire space is the set of natural number sequences $ \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ equipped with the product topology (where $\mathbb{N}$ has the discrete topology). What follows is my statement and proof of the fact that sets of sequences with a common prefix form a base for Baire space. Note that, if $w \in \mathbb{N}^*$ is a string and $f \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence, I use notation $w \sqsubseteq f$ to mean $w$ is a prefix of $f$. I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to prove this.

**Proposition**

The set 
$$ \mathcal{B} = \lbrace \lbrace f \in  \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N} } \; | \; w  \sqsubseteq f \rbrace \; | \; w \in \mathbb{N}^* \rbrace  $$
is a base for Baire space.

**Proof.**
 Let $\pi_n : \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ be the projection onto the $n$'th component. Basic sets in the product topology are finite intersections of pre-images under projections $\pi_n : \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}  $. Therefore every basic open set is of the form 
$$\prod_{i = 0}^{k} A_i \times \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} $$
for some $k \in \mathbb{N} $, where the $A_i \subseteq \mathbb{N} $ are subsets. Now let $U$ be an open set in Baire space and $f \in U$. Then there exist subsets $A_0, ..., A_k \subseteq \mathbb{N} $ such that 
$$f \in \prod_{i = 0}^{k} A_i \times \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \subseteq U $$
Now suppose that $ f(i) = a_i$ for $i \in \lbrace 0, ..., k \rbrace$. Then 
$$f \in \prod_{i = 0}^{k} \lbrace a_i \rbrace \times \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \subseteq \prod_{i = 0}^{k} A_i \times \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \subseteq U $$
Letting $w = a_0 \cdot \cdot \cdot a_k$, we have $w \sqsubseteq f$, so that 
$f \in \lbrace g \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \; : \; w \sqsubseteq g \rbrace \subseteq U$

I'm hoping that somebody has a suggestion for better notation which would make this proof look more elegant and neat. This idea is quite simple, and I feel frustrated to have to write so much!

Comment: What are you taking as the definition of "product topology"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\N{\mathbb{N}}$For $w ∈ \N^*$ we define $B_w := \{f ∈ \N^\N: w \sqsubseteq f\}$.

Let $f ∈ \N^\N$, let $∏_{i ∈ \N} U_i$ be a basic neighborhood of $f$, let $n ∈ \N$ be such that $U_i = \N$ for $i ≥ n$. Then $f ∈ B_{f\restriction n} = ∏_{i < n} \{f(i)\} × ∏_{i ≥ n} \N ⊆ ∏_{i ∈ \N} U_i$.

This is exacly your proof, just written more concise and using some additional notation.